# Network related part of a script will not run in /lib/systemd/system-sleep

Tags: networking, scripts, suspend, systemd, resume

The purpose of the script is to re-enable a hidden SSID upon resume from sleep.  Somehow the ability to restart a hidden SSID automatically was lost when I upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

You can see from the script below how many ways I have tried to get this to work. The `echo` print to `suspend.txt` works every time upon resume. It is just the portion to restart the wifi that does not work.
All the commands I tried in the script work as expected when entered on the CLI and the `/home/user/Desktop/wifi-ssid.sh` works when double clicked.

The results from `journalctl | grep systemd-sleep` is below the script.  Most notable is the error...

```
"Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device lo not available because device is strictly unmanaged)."
```

This must be something simple.  Please help.

---

```bash
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/user/Desktop

case "$1" in
    pre)
            #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending
    ;;
    post)
            #code execution AFTER resuming
            echo "$(date) - $1: test pre" >> /home/user/tmp/suspend.txt
            /usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID"
            #/usr/bin/nmcli radio wifi on
          #sleep 2
          #/usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID"
            #/home/user/Desktop/wifi-ssid.sh
            #su user -c "/home/user/Desktop/wifi-ssid.sh"
            #su user -c "/usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID""
            #/usr/bin/sudo -u user bash -c "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000; /home/user/Desktop/wifi-ssid.sh"
            #/usr/bin/sudo -u user bash -c "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID""
            #/usr/bin/sudo -u user bash -c "/home/user/Desktop/wifi-ssid.sh"            
            #su user -c "/usr/bin/nmcli con up SSID"
            #/usr/bin/sudo -u user bash -c "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000; /usr/bin/nmcli con up SSID; /usr/bin/nmcli radio wifi on; sleep 2; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID""
            
     ;;
esac

exit 0
```

---

`journalctl | grep systemd-sleep` shows the following:

```
Mar 03 16:53:30 User systemd-sleep[4074]: Suspending system...  
Mar 03 20:01:32 User systemd-sleep[4074]: System resumed.  
Mar 03 20:01:32 User systemd-sleep[4206]: /dev/sda:  
Mar 03 20:01:32 User systemd-sleep[4206]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)  
Mar 03 20:01:32 USer systemd-sleep[4206]:  APM_level = 0  
Mar 03 20:01:32 User systemd-sleep[4189]: Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device lo not available because device is strictly unmanaged).
```

Answer (score 4):

Networking is not made available until all scripts in the `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` directory finish executing.

Try sending networking related commands to the background with a delay of e.g. 10 seconds in a sub-shell and detach it i.e. change:

```bash
/usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID"
```

to:

```bash
(sleep 10; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID") & disown
```

**Notice** that `disown` is a `bash` builtin and depending on your system shell configuration `/bin/sh` might be linked to a different shell command interpreter other than `bash` .... For such case, you might call `/bin/bash` using a command string like so:

```bash
/bin/bash -c '(sleep 10; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID") & disown'
```

Or even in most cases calling `/bin/sh` with a sub-shell in a command string i.e. like so:

```sh
/bin/sh -c '(sleep 10; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id "SSID") &'
```

should fork a new detached process.

**Another** thing that you might need to keep that process alive is to explicitly specify/switch to a user e.g. your `username` or even `root` if your command/script requires elevated privileges to execute ... You can do this as well in a command string style but, you need to use different quoting style i.e. double quotes `/bin/su username -c "/bin/bash -c '...'"` e.g. like so:

```sh
/bin/su username -c "/bin/bash -c '(sleep 10; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id SSID) & disown'"
```

changing `username` to a valid account's user name on the system e.g. your actual account login user name.

Comment: Your last two suggestions did not work, but the 'Error:' went away in journalctl.The first suggestion returned an error ':disown: not found'

Comment: @toddk63 I have updated the answer for that one on how to keep the background process alive until it does its job.

Comment: It worked!...with "/bin/su root" but not "/bin/su username".  Thank you for the help.

Comment: @toddk63 You are welcome ... You did change `username` to e.g. your actual account login user name ... If so, then your command requires elevated privileges to execute and specifying `root` as a user is mandatory in such case.

Comment: Yes I did try actual "username", so "root" was required

Comment: /bin/su root -c "/bin/bash -c '(sleep 10; /usr/bin/nmcli c up id SSID) & disown'"