# Ubuntu 22.04 jammy run script on resume

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, suspend, pulseaudio

When i wake my laptop from sleep the sound doesn't work but `pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start` fixes it. I want to run this as a wake up script. A good search reveals that the trick is to put a script in `/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep/` however, /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep is not a directory - its a file. If you cat the file a lot of is isn't output as text.

Any ideas? basically I need to run the command above on wakeup.

Answer (score 1):

It's `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and **not** "*`/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep`*" ... Your scriptfile's contents can look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# "/lib/systemd/system-sleep/" template script

case "${1}" in
  pre)
    # Command(s)/script(s) to execute before system goes to sleep/hibernate
    # nothing
      ;;
  post)
    # Command(s)/script(s) to execute after system wakes up from sleep/hibernate
    /bin/pulseaudio --kill && /bin/pulseaudio --start
    # To run a command as a certain user, use the example below instead ...
    # Changing "username" to the actual desired invoking user name like:
    # /bin/su username -c '/bin/pulseaudio --kill && /bin/pulseaudio --start'
      ;;
esac
```

Yo need to specify full real path to executables and in case of user services like PulseAudio, you might need to specify the invoking user as well.

You'll obviously need to create the script file, edit and save it first with e.g.:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/script-file-name
```

Then, make it executable like so:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/script-file-name
```

---

You might need to read these related posts as well:

- [Network related part of a script will not run in /lib/systemd/system-sleep](https://askubuntu.com/a/1457707)
- [Shell script works manually but doesn't work correctly in Crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465201)

Comment: This worked exactly, thanks a bunch!